# Disabling touchEnd when pressing buttons

Tags: touch, livecode, swipe-gesture

I have a game which is controlled through swipe gestures.
Each turn, the user swipes and it moves pieces on the screen.

My problem is, when pressing the "Start" button, the game starts and sometimes records the first swipe gesture at the same time.

How do I disable the touch messages when I am pressing a button?

Comment: Do you have card level touchStart handlers, etc?  Adding a started/running flag to tell when the game is in play would solve the problem - also useful if you can pause the game.  It's easier to make suggestions if you post some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `touchEnd` handler to the Start button:

```
on touchEnd
end touchEnd
```

As long as you don't have a `pass touchEnd` command in this handler, the `touchEnd` handler higher up de message hierarchy won't run.

Another possibility is to check for `the target` higher up the message hierarchy:

```
on touchEnd
  if the short name of the target is "Start" then
    exit touchEnd
  else
    // remainder of your script
  end if
end touchEnd
```